# client server timer , that displayed in client side (js) and can't be cheated

Tags: javascript, server-side

i have client side game in js that have stage which count down the time in minutes 
now i save few steps of the game in server side also .
but i know that sometimes that browser is slow and less responsive so the 4 minutes i count in the server side are not 4 minutes in the client .
how can i make this consist?
so its can't be cheated ?

Answer (score 0):

Build a keep-alive system. Every 30 seconds or so, send in a time-dependent variable (timestamp or encrypted variation thereof), and get it received by the server. Server calculates the difference, sends back the difference to the client. This way, you know every 30s what the difference is, which allows you to adjust accordingly.

This does not cover for lag - instead, it allows you to adapt. This also does not take into account the time it takes for the request to fire, so take the difference with a pinch of salt.

Comment: one thing i need to consider is as much less requests doing to the server

Comment: This is why I suggested requesting every 30 seconds. On average, that's 8 requests per 4min timer, and all you need to do in terms of ops on the server is this: `<?php echo time()-$user_timer; ?>` (after validation of the user's timestamp, obviously).